# What is the formal terminology for emotion recognition AI?

Tags: terminology, facial-recognition, affective-computing, emotion-recognition

I'm researching the use of emotion recognition in Intelligent Tutoring Systems and trying to more effectively find and formally reference materials. My question is whether this is the most formal terminology (i.e. "emotion recognition"), because I've also seen "affect recognition" and "affective computing". Maybe it's a matter of taste, but I know sometimes the market terminology is different from the engineering terminology and I'd like to be more in tune with the engineers.

Maybe there is a leading classification system of related technologies (e.g. facial recognition, sentiment analysis, etc.)?

I'm seeing the "affective-computing" tag now, but not sure if these tags reflect a formal classification system in the field of AI.